# find any of three metacharacters in different strings

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently having this issue.

I have several variables like these

```
var1 = '\nHost(`ohio.dev.hiphop.org`) || (Host(`jersey.hiphop.org`) && Path(`/`))\n'

var2 = '\nHost(`westcoast.dev.hiphop.org`,`eastcoast.dev.hiphop.org`,`texas.dev.hiphop.org`) || (Host(`wutang.dev.hiphop.org`) && Path(`/`))\n'
```

In any of these variables, there can be a `|` or a `&` or a `,` that will appear first. For var1, it will be the `|`. and for var2, it will be `,`.

I'm looking for a way to find, any of these metacharacters, regardless of their orders. When found, it will do the following

```
metalist = [',','|','&']
if var1.count(first_metacharacter_found_in_the_variable_in_the_metalist) >0 :
    var1.split(first_metacharacter_found_in_the_variable_in_the_metalist)
```

Same for var2

```
metalist = [',','|','&']
if var2.count(first_metacharacter_found_in_the_variable_in_the_metalist) >0 :
    var2.split(first_metacharacter_found_in_the_variable_in_the_metalist)
```

The results for var1 would `\nHost(`ohio.dev.hiphop.org`)`  and the results for var2 would be `'\nHost(`westcoast.dev.hiphop.org``

I've thought of using regex but I'm not sure about it.

Any thoughts are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution would do the trick:

Use a regex with the `|`, which means the logical condition OR.
It does gives us something like this `"\,|\&|\|"` (`,` OR `|` OR `&`
)
We then look for which metacharacter, comes first and put them into sep (for separator)

```
sep = re.findall("\,|\&|\|", var1)[0]

sep = re.findall("\,|\&|\|", var2)[0]
```

Then we split the string, using the dynamically generated separator

```
var1.split(sep, 1)[0]

var2.split(sep, 1)[0]
```

Which gives the code below (you need to replace `<replace var>` with var1 or var2)

```
if re.findall("\,|\&|\|", <replace var>):
    sep = re.findall("\,|\&|\|", <replace var>)[0]
    <replace var> = <replace var>.split(sep, 1)[0]
```

Comment: You don't need the `|` (or) operator. Just use a string like in `'[,&|]'`.